# Prove the series converges $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{\sqrt{k}k^k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Set $$b_n= \frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{\sqrt{k}k^k}$$

I need to show this decreases and goes to 0 with the limit. But the limit part is throwing me off because:

$$\lim_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k = \frac{\sqrt{\infty+1}}{\sqrt{\infty}\infty^{\infty}}$$

even if I:

$$\lim_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{k}{k}+\frac{1}{k}}}{k^{k+\frac{1}{2}}}$$

which gives me $1$ in the numerator and I don't even know what in the denominator

How do I take the  derivative to show that it is decreasing? like is one to differentiate $k^k$?

Comment: For $k\geq 1$, $\sqrt{k+1} \leq \sqrt{2k}$ so $$\frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{\sqrt{k}k^k} \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{k^k}$$ can you handle $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^k}$?

Comment: No have a variable to another variable is confusing. I never even saw anything like that in calculus 3. It is very foreign

Comment: If that bothers you, then observe that for $k\geq 2$ you have $1/k^k \leq 1/k^2$.

Comment: is $\frac{1}{k} \geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{k^k}$

Comment: Yes (ignore the $\sqrt{2}$, it changes nothing to the argument), but $1/k$ won't help you here. $1/k^2$ would, however.

Comment: $\lim_{k=1}^\infty$ should probably just read $\lim_{k\to\infty}$. I've never seen a limit written the way you have before and I can only assume it's meant to mean what I've written. However I didn't make an edit because perhaps I'm mistaken, please check.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
$$
\frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{k^k \sqrt{k}}
 = \frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{\sqrt{k}} \times \frac1{k^k}
 = \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{k}} \times \frac1{k^k}
$$

Comment: I think I can handle it from there

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It's an alternating series, we can use a test for alternating series convergence: [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test).

Comment: That's... overkill. That thing converges absolutely, the summand goes down faster than exponentially.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\cfrac{\sqrt{n+2}}{\sqrt{n+1} (n+1)^{n+1}}\right)}{\left(\cfrac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt n n^n}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1-\frac1{(n+1)^2}}\cdot\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^n\cdot\frac1{n+1}$$

All that is left is to prove this limit is less than $1.$

In fact, one can say the series converges *absolutely*.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the ratio test by proving that the series 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{k^{k+1/2}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^kb_{k}
$$
is absolutely convergent.

Since

$$
b_{k+1}=\frac{\sqrt{k+2}}{(k+1)^{k+3/2}},
$$
we have
$$
\frac{b_{k+1}}{b_{k}}=\frac{\sqrt{k+2}}{(k+1)^{k+3/2}}\cdot\frac{k^{k+1/2}}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^{k}\frac{\sqrt{k(k+2)}}{(k+1)^2}=\frac{1}{k}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{-k}\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{k}}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^2},
$$
Hence 
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{b_{k+1}}{b_{k}}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{-k}\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{k}}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^2}=0\cdot e^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{1}}{(1)^2}=0.
$$
This shows that the series converges absolutely, and therefore it converges.

Comment: I think the second to last equality might be wrong; $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\frac2k}=1$